# Setting DockPanel height programmatically on startup

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a Windows form application. I am using Nuget DockPanel. Problem that I am facing is that it shows minimum dock panel height when I start my app. As shown in picture:

[Please click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApBYp.png)
In Image the area with blue pen line is form size and the area with black pen line is Dock Panel area

I want to set some height for DockPanel on start, it works only when I resize with mouse. The height of Dock Panel and form in this panel should be same.

```
 public partial class MainForm: Form
 {
          public MainForm()
          {
             InitializeComponent();
             DockPanel footerDockPanel = new DockPanel();
             footerDockPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
             this.Controls.Add(footerDockPanel);
             Errorform = new ErrorForm();
             Errorform.Show(footerDockPanel, DockState.DockBottom);
             InfoForm = new InformationForm();
             InfoForm.Show(footerDockPanel, DockState.DockBottom);
           }
 }
public partial class ErrorForm : DockContent
{
    public ErrorForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Error form and Information form have the same code.both are inherited to DockContent class

Comment: Please could you post some code from `InitializeComponent()`-method which shows, how your controls are arranged? Which one has which docking and anchoring.

Comment: Use DockPanel.MinHeight https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minheight(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Question is edited please review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your code above, it worked when just adding the line

```
footerDockPanel.Height = 600;
```

**Edit:**
[image]

**Edit 2:**
There is a property `DockBottomPortion` on `DockPanel` which describes how many percent of the heigth should be used for the `DockContent`. Setting it to 0.99 means 99%. Values of 1.00 and above are interpreted as fixed sizes.

```
footerDockPanel.DockBottomPortion = 0.99;
```

Comment: Its not working I set height before but on start of app its height is like image show. after that it's height can be modified upto height that i was set. I need to set height on start.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added a picture to show you how I did it. If it behaves different on your machine, maybe you have some additional code you didn't mention which screws it up.

Comment: I this case Error Form and information form's height is not equal to dock panel height. please if you change the backcolor of footerdockpenl it its height is much greater then the both forms

Comment: I edit your answer pleas check the image with Pleasseetheimage link

Comment: Please edit your question instead of editing my answer ;-)

Comment: I am sorry I am new here on stack overflow

Comment: Did you try `DockBottomPortion` as suggested on my 2nd edit?

Comment: Thank you so much @Thoma it is working according to my need

Answer (score 0):

if Its Empty, you can put a panel in it and set size for panel